# how to trace SSRS stats

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

we have a large SSRS 2016 reports list

I would like to monitor these SSRS reports

and by monitor I mean to know

- how many users opens them
- what are the parameters were chosen
- how long did it take to load that report
- how long did the user spend opening that report

is there a way from the SSRS server allows me to get this stat

or is there any script I can add to the reports to get this stat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this against your report server DB

```
use [ReportServer]
SELECT 
R.Name
,R.ItemID 
, L.TimeDataRetrieval
,L.TimeProcessing 
,L.TimeRendering 
, L.TimeDataRetrieval+L.TimeProcessing+L.TimeRendering AS TotalTime
,L.Format
,L.[Parameters]
,L.username
,L.TimeStart 
,L.TimeEnd
,l.ReportID


,DATEDIFF(SECOND,L.timestart,L.timeend) time_seconds
,r.Path

FROM dbo.ExecutionLog L  

INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog R  
    ON L.ReportID = R.ItemID 
    
WHERE R.Name like  'name of your report'
```

it will give you everything you have asked for.. comment out the where caluse for all the reports. You have somewhere to start.

Comment: Just to add to Harry's answer. Also, by default, the execution log is only retained for 60 days. I increased this to 400 days so I can see annually (plus 1 quarter) how frequently reports were used (or not at all). You can change the retention periods by connecting to the ssrs service in SSMS and looking at properties. You might also want to start with the catalog and left join to the execution log if you want to capture unused reports.